# Scaled plotting of multiple pairwise Venn diagrams in R

Tags: r, venn-diagram, eulerr

I want to plot >50 Venn/Euler diagrams of two sets each to scale.
It is necessary that not only the overlap of the two sets and the set size themselves should scale but also the size of the individual diagrams compared to each other.

Since I know of no R package that allows the plotting of >50 pairwise Venn diagrams at the same time, I was planning to plot them first individually (e.g., using `eulerr`) and then put all of them together using the `gridExtra` package or something similar.

However, in this way, the size of the individual pairwise diagrams is not comparable:

```
require(gridExtra)
require(eulerr)
fit1 <- euler(c(A=300, B=500, "A&B"=100))
fit2 <- euler(c(A=40, B=70, "A&B"=30))
grid.arrange(plot(fit1), plot(fit2), nrow=1)
```

Does anyone know of an R package or a combination of packages that would allow size-appropriate plotting of several pairwise Venn diagrams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `widths` argument of `grid.arrange`. You would have to determine the ratio of each of the venn diagrams' totals. In your example, the total size ratio is `800:110`, which is `7.27`, so if you do `grid.arrange(plot(fit1), plot(fit2), ncol = 2, widths = c(7.27, 1))` then `fit2` will be much smaller than `fit1`. The `ggarrange()` function from ggpubr should work also.

```
fit1 <- euler(c(A=300, B=500, "A&B"=100))
fit2 <- euler(c(A=40, B=70, "A&B"=30))

tot1 <- 800
tot2 <- 110
ratio_v <- tot1/tot2

grid.arrange(plot(fit1), plot(fit2), ncol = 2, widths = c(ratio_v, 1))
ggpubr:ggarrange(plotlist = list(plot(fit1), plot(fit2)), ncol = 2, widths = c(ratio_v, 1))
```

[image]

Edit: Want the individual pairwise sets to have their own size ratios, instead of everything relative to a global maximum. This is a simple example, but you can write a function to do this automatically for each one. Basically set the maximum number of columns (I just chose 100), and then convert each of your ratios to be out of 100. Make a row for each venn diagram set, then `rbind` them all into a matrix and use the `layout_matrix` argument.

```
### Make fits
fit1 <- euler(c(A=300, B=500, "A&B"=100))
fit2 <- euler(c(A=40, B=70, "A&B"=30))
fit3 <- euler(c(C=100, D=300, "C&D"=50))
fit4 <- euler(c(C=50, D=80, "C&D"=30))

### Assign totals 
tot1 <- 800
tot2 <- 110
tot3 <- 400
tot4 <- 130

### Find ratios
ratioAB_v <- round(tot1/tot2)
ratioCD_v <- round(tot3/tot4)

### Convert ratios
smallAB_v <- round(1/ratioAB_v*100)
smallCD_v <- round(1/ratioCD_v*100)

### Make rows
row1_v <- c(rep(1, (100-smallAB_v)), rep(2, smallAB_v))
row2_v <- c(rep(3, (100-smallCD_v)), rep(4, smallCD_v))

### Make matrix
mat <- rbind(row1_v, row2_v)

### Plot
grid.arrange(plot(fit1), plot(fit2), plot(fit3), plot(fit4), layout_matrix = mat)
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine, thank you. Is there also an option to adjust the widths for each row individually when plotting the diagrams both in columns and rows?

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about that. So that each pair has their own ratio, independent of the other pairs? I've updated with a version I think answers your question, you'll just have to generalize it so you can run it on all 50+ pairs together.